# How to add Sinon to angular 2 testing?

Tags: unit-testing, angular, sinon

I want to add Sinon for testing but I can't get it to run.

I've installed sinon and karma-sinon as DevDependencies.

added sinon to Frameworks in my karma config file.

```
 frameworks: ['jasmine', 'browserify','sinon'],
```

and in my test file I'm trying to declare a spy

```
let setTokenSpy = sinon.spy(sbHttpObiject, 'checkForToken');
```

and I'm getting

> TypeScript error: app/sdk/test/http.spec.ts(87,22): Error TS2304:
>   Cannot find name 'sinon'.

Any help much appreciated! Btw, i think jasmine has also spies but i can't get them to run either, any updates on that?

EDIT----------------------------
---------09.09.2016

meanwhile i've found out that I need to install typings like

> typings install dt~sinon --save --global

But now I'm getting this error

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: sinon in
>   /var/folders/ld/2g86bbq11tddvbnzlzbtg2r80000gn/T/78dc4c45b42a2dd7bfcfb607366d1d15.browserify
>   (line 350)

Comment: I guess that the issue is Browserify build rather than anything else. Also notice that `browserify` [should go first](https://github.com/nikku/karma-browserify#usage) in the list of the frameworks.

Comment: wow...that actually solved the sinon issue...thanks!!!